# I am considering a Tree Nav layout on webpage for ticket approvals. What could be some alternatives?

Tags: website-design

I'm trying to make a layout design for a process.
I have 3 types of users one is x , b and c.

x does some work, then b approves it, then c confirms it.
But b can disapprove and open a ticket for x on that same task and c can also do the same. It's confusing but I want to see them all in a single page which shows x did "work1" then  b approved it but c declined it but created a ticket called "work2". then x again did "work2" b approved it and then c confirmed it and the task ended.

It required some sort of a tree view according to my perspective what do you think what sort of tree view would be better?

Comment: I can't really picture how you would use a tree view to solve this problem so you might need to elaborate. I would take a look at other ticketing systems like Jira -- they don't typically display history information right up front. It's usually enough to know the current status and assignee of the ticket and if you wanted to know the history, you could go into the ticket's details.

Comment: Can the same task be over and over go A B C or just once ? Is this useful information ? I'm thinking showimg the last 1 or changes with a dropdown to see the history. But depends.

Comment: yes its a task but the task can have many cases.. x submits saying the task is done but b finds a new problem or a case in that task so b creates a case on that task elaborating what the problem is then x submits fixing that thing then b accepts then c.. @Justin yes i need this information.. clients wants it bad

Comment: To me it is about 2 things. The status of the task and the history log of the task. The status needs no further navigation than selecting a status. The history log can be completed with comments.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is have the ticket history upfront for the team to see. Github does this really well on pull requests. Multiple people can review pull requests, leave comments etc. Different actions are signified with different symbols on the timeline. Reddit is also a good example to refer to.

Github pull request review:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, we have 3 roles with specified permissions:

1. X - *make work*
2. B - *confirm work* or *reject work*(return to X)
3. C - *verify work* or *reject work*(return to X)

Ok, as i see it:

- at the moment when role **B** or **C** rejects work, it makes no sense to create **work2** (more clutter record, more logic, creating unnecessary resources, archiving old ones  etc.) but operate under **work1**
- I used to design something similar to implementation, and with team we working on
  **the status** (additional parameter)

You don't need a tree (surely) until you plan to list these works and then group them into level II or III scopes (it already requires a complicated backend)

[image]

enter image description here

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: yes you got it but one think was off. Before B and c rejects or accepts. They need to make a comment about it. so i wanted to show that comment as well. You have helped me to some extend thanks can you provide a ui design just a structure if you have an idea. thank you sir

Comment: ok, if You provide me with a screen with the system, I will try to provide a quick sketch for tomorrow evening :)

Comment: how can i provide a screen i dont get it

Comment: This layout is something new? or You need to add this to existing system?

Comment: its new.  i just need a page where I show it.